# How to use Restcall with Spring Security

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

In my Spring MVC application I am using spring security. It works fine so far, but I have to admit, I do not understand all the details.

In the same application the user can call some controller functions by rest api. When the user (lets say Tom) does this, his authentication is lost. Instead the controller is called by user anonymous.

I tracked down that "user switch" to the code below. Variable restCall contains an url to my application. That call would work for user Tom, if he would place it in the browser directly. Using the restcall, the user changes to anyonymous.

1) Can I prevent that, when the calling User (Tom) was already logged in?
2) As those services should be called by a user that is not already browsing the web interface of the application, I would have to find a way to login by the rest call itself.

```
private void callWebservice(HttpServletRequest req, String restCall) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    ResponseEntity<String> response
      = restTemplate.getForEntity(restCall, String.class);

    logger.debug(response.toString());

    //assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need, for example, a  JSON Web Token (JWT) Authentication.

Steps are the following:

1) Client does an authentication, a post request with username and password

2) If authentication is successful, server returns a token in which is coded the user

3) In your next call, GET or POST, you add JWT to your `header`, this way the server will know who you are, because server can decode the token, and can grant also the right authorities and functionalities